# how to handle nodejs bluebird error for chain promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I have 2 functions which return promises. But i want to throw an error in one place for both functions. Currently I'm getting a catch handler only for the 2nd function.
Below is my code

```
modules.function1(sUserData)
  .then(function(finalResult) {
    console.log("controller Final result " + finalResult)
    return finalResult;
  }).then(function(finalResult) {
    console.log('call generateJson');
    return modules.modelClip.function2();
  }).then(function(finalResult) {
    console.log('helper result : ', finalResult);
  }).error(function(e) {
    console.log("controller Error handler " + e)
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("controller Catch handler " + e)
  });
```

Below is function1 code

```
exports.function1 = function(sResultDetail) {
  console.log('inside function1');
  return new modules.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      reject(new Error("error_34"));// or resolve('success');
  });
}
```

Below is function2 code

```
exports.function2 = function(sResultDetail) {
  console.log('inside function2');
  return new modules.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      reject(new Error("error_34"));// or resolve('success');
  });
}
```

So how to get an error for both function at one place, meaning in 1st call. Can i achieve or is there a any other way to do something similar? Any help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: I don't really get what your problem is. What do you mean by "*I'm getting a catch handler only for the 2nd function*"? What's the current output of your code, and how is that different from the expected?

Comment: when i  do this in any function reject(new Error("error_34"));, i get error in catch function not in actual error function, i should get error in error function not in catch.

Comment: No [you should not](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html), why do you think so? Why don't you simply use a single `.catch()` (and no `.error()`) if you want to catch everything?

Comment: Please see stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it